# phpmailer seems not working with gmail

Tags: smtp, gmail, phpmailer

when I try to send email using phpmailer with gmail stp, seems doesn't working. I have tested all solutions proposed but still this issue:

```
2017-01-27 19:29:33 Invalid address:  (addAnAddress Reply-To): jgh
2017-01-27 19:29:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-khadija.genious.net ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Fri, 27 Jan 2017 19
:29:33 +0000 
                                      220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited
, 
                                      220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2017-01-27 19:29:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mywebsite.ma
2017-01-27 19:29:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-khadija.genious.net Hello khadija.genious.net [41.77.119.226
]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250 HELP
2017-01-27 19:29:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2017-01-27 19:29:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2017-01-27 19:29:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mywebsite.ma
2017-01-27 19:29:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-khadija.genious.net Hello khadija.genious.net [41.77.119.226
]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
                                      250 HELP
2017-01-27 19:29:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2017-01-27 19:29:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2017-01-27 19:29:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx==
2017-01-27 19:29:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2017-01-27 19:29:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx
2017-01-27 19:29:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 Incorrect authentication data
2017-01-27 19:29:35 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data
2017-01-27 19:29:35 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2017-01-27 19:29:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2017-01-27 19:29:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 khadija.genious.net closing connection
2017-01-27 19:29:35 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Here is my php page:

```
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
require 'class.smtp.php';

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = "XXX@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "XXX";

$email_recipient = 'XXX@gmail.com';

$mail->setFrom($email_recipient);
$mail->addAddress($email_recipient);  
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email']);

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$mail->Body    = "Message";

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo json_encode(array('result' => false));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('result' => true));
}
```

I have already enabled lesssecureapps : https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Base your code on the Gmail example provided, and read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide. You can't see what is happening because you're not showing server output (`SMTPDebug=2`), which is pretty much the first thing that most of the answers on here suggest.

Comment: @Synchro I have added in my message the return of detailed debug

Comment: So it doesn't like your password?

Comment: @Synchro I don't know exactly, I'm sure login and password works good if I login manually in gmail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ISP is redirecting your SMTP connection to their own mail server. You are asking to connect to `smtp.gmail.com`, but you are ending up on `khadija.genious.net`, and of course your credentials do not work on there.

I would guess you are running PHP older than 5.6; this is a good lesson in why not verifying TLS certificates is a bad idea - you have effectively given away you Gmail credentials to an MITM attacker. This is covered in the troubleshooting guide.

Comment: Synchro, I have updated my php version to 5.6.17, but still issue, I think my hosting don't allow to use smtp or something like that? Here is the message : http://pastebin.com/5J9R1kKV

Comment: So not only is your ISP redirecting you, they are doing so incompetently. I suggest you find a new ISP.